# Are \bibentry and \subfile incompatible? [! LaTeX Error: Cannot be used in preamble.]

Tags: bibentry

I am trying to construct a report document that consists of a series of documents that can also be compiled individually. In these subfile documents I have been using \bibentry{} from the bibentry package to allow me to print a full citation in text.

Compiling the subfile documents individually works fine, and if I comment out the "\bibentry" line in the subfile the main document is fine, but compiling the main file with the \bibentry in the subfile fails and I receive the error

[! LaTeX Error: Cannot be used in preamble.]

Any advice would be welcomed. I'm not sure where to start with my troubleshooting.

Thanks.

The following files provide a minimal working example:

---

File Name: MainDocument.tex

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}

%For inclusion of subfiles
    \usepackage{subfiles}

%Path to the directory containing: "MainDocument.tex", "SubfileDocument.tex", and "Bibliography.bib"
        \newcommand{\Troubleshooting}{Path to Troubleshooting Directory/MWE_SubfilesWithBibEntries/}

%%Bibliography
%%       %Allows display of a full bib entry using the command \bibentry{citationkey}
       \usepackage{bibentry}
       \nobibliography*

        \newcommand{\Bibliography}{Bibliography.bib}
        \def\biblio{\bibliographystyle{siam}\bibliography{\Troubleshooting\Bibliography}}

%Document Information
\title{This Is a Document}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First}\newpage
\subfile{\Troubleshooting SubfileDocument.tex}\newpage
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{\Troubleshooting\Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

---

File Name: SubfileDocument.tex

```
\documentclass[Path to to troubleshooting directory /MWE_SubfilesWithBibEntries/MainDocument.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\section{first Section}
Interesting words here that describe something cool.\\
Print text of relevant source:\\
\bibentry{testcitation}\\
Cite relevant source \cite{testcitation}
\biblio
\end{document}
```

---

File Name: Bibliography.bib

```
@article{testcitation,
abstract = {Words and more word},
author = {John Doe},
doi = {},
file = {},
journal = {Journal of Amazing Things},
keywords = {},
mendeley-tags = {},
month = {aug},
number = {8},
pages = {1000-1005},
publisher = {Publisher of Cool Things},
title = {{Article of Cool Things}},
url = {},
volume = {7},
year = {1995}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: yes, there are incompatible. The problem is a bit tricky. The command `\bibentry` uses `\nocite` which should not be used in the preamble. The problem actually has nothing to do with `bibentry`. You would have the same problem just using `\nocite` in the subfile.

Normally, when latex encounters `\begin{document}`, it first executes `\document` and then changes its meaning into `\@onlypreamble`.

The `\nocite` command first checks whether the value of `\document` is `\@onlypreamble`. If not, it is still in the preamble and issues an error message.

Now, the `\subfile` command changes `\document` to do nothing and inputs your subfile.

When `\bibentry` is encountered is the subfile, it executes `\nocite` but since the value of `\document` is not `\@nopreamble` it deduces that it is still in the preamble hence the error.

Now, how to correct this? The package `subfiles` actually only contains

```
\newcommand{\skip@preamble}{%
  \let\document\relax\let\enddocument\relax%
  \newenvironment{document}{}{}%
  \renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][subfiles]{}}
\newcommand\subfile[1]{\begingroup\skip@preamble\input{#1}\endgroup}
```

Instead of loading the package `subfiles`, just put in the preamble of you main document

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\subfile[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][subfiles]{}%
  \renewenvironment{document}{\let\document\@onlypreamble}{}%
  \input{#1}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

If you want to be able to use it as well in the subfiles, put this code in a file `mysubfiles.sty` and load `mysubfiles` instead of `subfiles`. This way, latex will not load the package twice. Otherwise, you would get an error when you try to redefine `\subfile` in the subfiles because it is already defined in the main file.

```
% mysubfiles.sty
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mysubfiles}

\newcommand\subfile[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\documentclass}[2][subfiles]{}%
  \renewenvironment{document}{\let\document\@onlypreamble}{}%
  \input{#1}%
  \endgroup}
```